# HP 530 Wireless problem. Bad communication with access point

Tags: wireless, connection, ndiswrapper, jockey, wicd

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on HP 530 and to make Wireless work installed STA driver from `jockey` (obviously proprietary) and, since it didn't work also installed their driver from HP website via `ndiswrapper`.
After this (and a reboot) I see the WiFi indicator glowing, like it should be, and I am able to find local access points. But when I try to connect to mine personal one with WPA 2 security (with password) it hangs at authentification (I'm using `wicd` to manage wifi), and after a minute or so (I guess timeout of request happens) it says I have a wrong password (it is 100% correct). What might be the problem here?

Yesterday I was able to connect to access point by changing type of encryption from `passphrase` to `preshared key` but didn't have internet access. Now, after reboot, I can't connect there again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Natty and that was just a dhcp problem.
A static ip adress fix the problem in my case.

Hope that will be helpful for someone ...

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already switched to Crunchbang linux, where everything worked out-of-box.